# How to set content loaded by ajax in detail view upon + icon click

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-table

When user clicks on + icon, I want to load some data from remote and add the content in the detial view for that clicked row. 
On 'onExpandRow' event, there is no clue about html element and neither 'detailFormatter' has any clue of html element.
Can anybody please suggest how to get the detail view html element?

Comment: More details, please. Would you be able to post some sample code, either here or on jsFiddle?

Comment: Try adding a Plunker or Fiddle.

Comment: do you have any samples on jsfiddler?We like to help :)

Comment: After trying, I figured a workaround. I had to catch 'expand-row.bs.table' event.  $table.on('expand-row.bs.table', function (event, index, row) {
            var expandedRowSelector = $('#tableId > tbody > tr[data-index="' + index + '"]').next('tr.detail-view').children('td')[0]; //ajax call then expandedRowSelector.innerHTML = remote_data

Comment: Here is the doc (there is a mistake in param doc) http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#events